The size of $A^\varepsilon$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $\varepsilon$ for bounded convex $A\subset\Bbb R^d$

Let $A$ be a bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $A^\varepsilon$ be the set of all points with the distance from $A$ at most $\varepsilon$. Prove that $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon)$, where $\lambda_d$ is Lebesgue measure, is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $\varepsilon$.

I do not know where to begin, so I'm trying to understand some basic examples. If $A = \{\ast\}$ is a singleton, then $A^\varepsilon$ is a ball centered at this point, and we know that $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon) \approx \varepsilon^d$. We can extend this to a finite collection $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon)$ may be hard to compute for general sets, so we should find a way to relate $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon)$ with $\lambda_d(A)$. I wrote $$\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon) = \int \mathbf{1}_{A^\varepsilon}(x)\, d\lambda_d(x),$$
and I suspect we can approximate $\mathbf{1}_{A^\varepsilon}$ by $\mathbf{1}_{A} \ast \varphi_\varepsilon$, where the latter is the convolution of $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ with a standard mollifier at scale $\varepsilon$. Precisely, $\varphi_\varepsilon(x) := \varepsilon^{-d} \varphi(x/\varepsilon)$ where $\varphi \in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$, $\int \varphi = 1$, and $\operatorname{supp}\varphi \subset B(0,1)$.
I'd appreciate any ideas for a solution! I do not see where convexity plays a role. It's quite interesting that we have a polynomial in $\varepsilon$ (i.e., some algebraic structure) regardless of whether $A$ is geometrically nice.

At first we prove the statement in several steps for a convex polytope, i.e. a convex hull of a finite set of points.
Step 1. The preparation.
Let $\Phi_k$ denote the set of all open $k$-dimensional faces of $A$ (i.e. open in the $k$-dimensional affine subspaces containing them), and let $F_k = \bigcup_{F \in \Phi_k} F$ be the union of all $k$-dimensional faces. Let $N$ denote the dimension of $A$, i.e. the dimension of the affine subspace $L \subset \mathbb R^d$ generated by $A$ (note that $A$ has interior points in $L$). Let $U = \mathbb R^d \setminus A$ and consider the function $p:U \rightarrow A$ that maps $x \in U$ to the (unique) closest point in $A$ to $x$. Finally, let $U_k = p^{-1}(F_k)$. Clearly, $\{U_k\}_{k = 0}^N$ are pairwise disjoint Borel subsets of $U$ such that $U = \bigcup_{k = 0}^N U_k$ (we need to check that our constructions turn out to be Borel sets in order to be able to take their Lebesgue measure; I shall further omit the proofs of such claims and even the claims themselves; if we use Lebesgue measure of something, then it should be easy to check that the set is Borel). I claim that $\lambda_d(U_k \cap A^\varepsilon)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le d$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, N$. From this we can conclude that $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon) = \lambda_d(A) + \sum_{k = 0}^N \lambda_d(A^\varepsilon \cap U_k)$ is again a polynomial of degree $\le d$ (clearly, the degree then equals exactly $d$, since for large $\varepsilon$ the measure $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon)$ asymptotically coincides with $C\varepsilon^d$, where $C$ is the measure of the unit ball).
Step 2. Reduction of the claim.
Now we fix $k \in \{0, \dots, K\}$ and consider the claim: $\lambda_d(U_k \cap A^\varepsilon)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le d$. Moreover, we need all $k$-dimensional faces $\Phi_k = \{\phi_1, \dots, \phi_m\}$, so $U_k = \bigcup_{l = 1}^m V_l$, where $V_l = p^{-1}(\phi_l)$ (note that the sets $V_l$ are pairwise disjoint). It suffices to prove that $\lambda_d(V_l \cap A^\varepsilon)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le d$ for each $l = 1, \dots, m$. We claim a more precise statement: $\lambda_d(V_l \cap A^\varepsilon)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d - k$. The proof relies on the following computation of the set $V_l \cap A^\varepsilon$. Let $T$ denote the affine subspace (of dimension $k$) generated by the face $\phi_l$. It is easy to see that for any $x \in \phi_l$ the vector $p(x) - x$ is orthogonal to $T$. Therefore, $V_l = \{x = a + b \in U: a \in \phi_l, b \in T^\perp, \|b\| \le \varepsilon, p(x) = a\}$. Consider $C = \{b \in T^\perp: \forall a \in \phi_l(a + b \notin A \wedge p(a + b) = a)\}$. I claim the following properties of $C$:

$C$ is a cone in $T^\perp$ (cone means that $\alpha b \in C$ for all $b \in C$ and $\alpha > 0$).
If $a \in \phi_l$ and $b \in T^\perp$ satisfy $a + b \notin A$ and $p(a + b) = a$, then $b \in C$ (that is, the quantifier $\forall$ can be replaced with $\exists$ in the definition of $C$).

If these are proved, then, clearly, $V_l \cap A^\varepsilon = \phi_l + \{b \in C: \|b\| \le \varepsilon\}$ and $\lambda_d(V_l \cap A^\varepsilon) = \lambda_k(\phi_l) \lambda_{d-k}(\{b \in C: \|b\| \le \varepsilon\})$. Since $C$ is a cone we write $\{b \in C: \|b\| \le \varepsilon\} = \varepsilon \{b \in C: \|b\| \le 1\}$ and $\lambda_{d-k}(\{b \in C: \|b\| \le \varepsilon\}) = \varepsilon^{d-k}\lambda_{d-k}(\{b \in C: \|b\| \le 1\})$, and the proof of the claim is complete.
Step 3. Proof of the statements 1 and 2 about $C$.
At first we fix any $a \in \phi_l$ and consider $C_a = \{b \in T^\perp: b + a \notin A, p(b+a) = a\}$. We prove that $C_a$ is a cone. At first note that $0 \notin C_a$, since $a + 0 \in A$. Let $b \in C_a$ and consider $\alpha > 0$. At first let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and suppose that $\alpha b + a \in A$. But then, clearly, $\alpha b + a$ is closer to $b + a$ than $a$, implying that $p(b + a) \ne a$. Therefore, $\alpha b + a \notin A$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Now assume that $p(\alpha b + a) \ne a$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. This assumption implies that distance from $\alpha b + a$ to $A$ is strictly less than $\alpha \|b\|$. Triangle ineaquality further shows that distance from $b + a$ is strictly less than $\|b\|$ contradicting $p(b + a) = a$. Thus, we conclude that distance from $\alpha b + a$ to $A$ is exactly $\alpha \|b\|$, so $p(\alpha b + a) = a$. Thus, $\alpha b \in C_a$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Now consider $I = \{\alpha > 0: \alpha b \in C_a\}$. From the foregoing proof we see that $I$ is a convex subset of $(0, +\infty)$ containing $(0,1)$. Assume that there exists $\beta \in (0, +\infty) \setminus I$, i.e. $I \subset (0, \beta)$. Clearly $\beta b + a \notin A$, otherwise $\alpha b + a \in A$ for all $\alpha \in (0, \beta)$ due to convexity of $A$. Therefore, (since we assumed $\beta \notin I$) $p(\beta b + a) \ne a$. Let $a' = p(\beta b + a)$ and choose $t \in (0,1)$ such that $a + b = (1-t)a + t(\beta b + a)$ (i.e. $t = 1/\beta$). Note that $\|\beta b + a - a'\| < \beta \|b\|$. Clearly, $$\|a + b - (1 - t)a - ta'\| =  \|(1-t)a + t(\beta b + a) - (1 - t)a - ta'\| =$$ $$t\|\beta b + a - a'\| < t \beta \|b\| = \|b\|.$$ That is, $(1-t)a + ta'$ is closer to $a + b$, than $a$ (i.e., $p(a+b) \ne a$). This contradiction finishes the proof that $C_a$ is a cone.
Now the statement 1 is clear as $C = \bigcap_{a \in \phi_l} C_a$. Also it is easy to notice that the statement 2 is in fact equivalent to the claim that $C_a$ does not depend on $a \in \phi_l$ (i.e. $C_a = C_{a'}$ for all $a,a' \in \phi_l$). Assume that $a,a' \in \phi_l$, $b \in C_a$, and $b \notin C_{a'}$. Let $x = p(b + a')$, so $\|b + a' - x\| < \|b\|$. The idea is to consider a point $a + t(x - a')$ with small $t > 0$ and notice that it is closer to $a + b$, than $a$ (indeed, consider $f(t) = \|a + b -a -  t(x - a')\|^2 = \|b - t(x - a')\|^2$; since this function of $t$ is a square polynomial and $f(1) < f(0)$ we conclude that $f$ decreases on the interval $[0,1]$). What remains to prove is that $a + t(x - a') \in A$ for small enough $t$. Now we consider cases $k = 0$ and $k > 0$. Clearly, if $k = 0$, then $\phi_l$ consists of exactly one point, so the claim is trivial. Otherwise, we finally can exploit the fact that $\phi_l$ is an open face: there exists $s > 1$ such that $(a - a')/t + a' \in \phi_l$ for $t \in (s^{-1}, 1)$. Now consider $t((a - a')/t + a') + (1-t)x = a + (1-t)(x - a')$. This point lies in $A$ due to convexity of $A$, so $a + t(x - a') \in A$ for $t \in (0, 1 - s^{-1})$. $\blacksquare$
Finally, the general case is a much simpler problem. At first note that it is enough to consider closed $A$, since $A^\varepsilon = (\overline{A})^{\varepsilon}$. Let $E$ denote the set of all extremal points of $A$, so $A$ is the convex hull of $E$. Let $\Lambda$ be the directed set of all finite subsets of $E$ and for $D \in \Lambda$ let $A_D$ denote the convex hull of $D$. Clearly, $\lambda_d(A^\varepsilon) = \sup_{D \in \Lambda} \lambda_d(A^\varepsilon_D) = \lim_{D \in \Lambda} \lambda_d(A^\varepsilon_D)$. It remains to note that the pointwise limit of a net of polynomials of degree $\le d$ is again a polynomial of the same degree.
